# How to cleanup the development datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

In Google App Engine Go SDK sometimes we can fill the local datastore with a bunch of test data. It's tiring to delete thousands of records 20 at a time using the web interface. Is there a command the erases the local datastore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply provide the `--clear_datastore` command line parameter when starting:

```
goapp serve --clear-datastore
```

Documented at: [The Go Development Server: Using the Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/devserver#Go_Using_the_Datastore).

> To clear the local datastore for an application, use the `--clear_datastore=yes` option when you start the web server:

Note that the documentation was "copied" from the Python section, you need to use it as presented above (you get an error if you try to execute `goapp serve --clear_datastore=yes`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Go, but in Java you can simply delete local_db.bin from `WEB-INF/appengine-generated` folder. An empty file will be created next time you run the app.